# debugging hadoop streaming progam

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-streaming

I have data in form

```
  id,    movieid      , date,    time
 3710100, 13502, 2012-09-10, 12:39:38.000
```

Now basically what I want to do is this..

I want to find out, how many times a particular movie is watched between 7 am and 11 am at 30 minute interval

So basically..

How many times movie has been watched between

```
  6 and 6:30
  6:30 and 7
   7 and 7:30
   ...
   10:30-11
```

So i wrote mapper and reducer to achieve this.

```
mapper.py

#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys

# input comes from STDIN (standard input)
for line in sys.stdin:
    # remove leading and trailing whitespace
    line = line.strip()
    # split the line into words
    line = line.split(",")
    #print line

    print '%s\t%s' % (line[1], line)
```

reducer.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import datetime
from collections import defaultdict



def convert_str_to_date(time_str):
    try:
        timestamp =   datetime.datetime.strptime(time_str, '%Y-%m-%d:%H:%M:%S.000')  #00:23:51.000


        return timestamp

    except Exception,inst:

        pass

def is_between(time, time1,time2):
    return True if time1 <= time < time2 else False


def increment_dict(data_dict, se10,date_time):
    start_time = datetime.datetime(date_time.year,date_time.month,date_time.day, 07,00,00)
    times = [start_time]
    for i in range(8):
        start_time += datetime.timedelta(minutes = 30 )
        times.append(start_time)
    for i in range(len(times) -1 ):
        if is_between(date_time, times[i], times[i+1]):
            data_dict[se10][i] += 1






keys = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]



data_dict = defaultdict(dict)


# input comes from STDIN
def initialize_entry(se10):
    for key in keys:
        data_dict[se10][key] = 0

for line in sys.stdin:
    # remove leading and trailing whitespace
    line = line.strip()


    # parse the input we got from mapper.py

    se10, orig_data = line.split('\t')
    initialize_entry(se10)
    parse_line = orig_data.split(",")

    datestr = parse_line[2].replace(" ","").replace("'","")
    timestr = parse_line[3].replace(" ","").replace("'","")

    date_time = datestr + ":" + timestr

    time_stamp = convert_str_to_date(date_time)

    increment_dict(data_dict, se10,time_stamp)


for key, secondary_key in data_dict.items():
    for skey, freq in secondary_key.items():
        print key,"," ,skey,",",freq
```

The above code runs just fine if i do the

```
   cat input.txt | python mapper.py | sort | python reducer.py
```

But when I deploy it on clusters. it fails saying that the job has been killed.. and that reason is unknow.

Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured this thing out..

The main issue was that my work local machine is windows based.. whereas the clusters are linux based..

so i had to convert the file written in dos to unix format..

Answer (score 0):

It is usually good idea to read through the logs in JobHistory, as described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/24509826/1237813 . It should give you more details why the job failed.

Regarding line endings, the class Hadoop Streaming uses by default to split lines is [TextInputFormat](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/TextInputFormat.html). It [used to break](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-473) with Windows newlines, but since 2006 it should work just fine.

That leaves your mapper and reducer scripts as a likely source of problems. Python 3 uses something called [universal newlines](https://docs.python.org/release/3.2/library/functions.html#open) and it should Just Work Out Of The Box with both Unix and Windows newlines. In Python 2.7, you need to explicitly switch it on.

On Linux and Mac OS X you can reopen stdin with universal newlines enabled like this `sys.stdin = open('/dev/stdin', 'U')`. I do not have a Windows computer at hand to try, but the following should work on all three systems:

```python
import os
import sys

# reopen sys.stdin
os.fdopen(sys.stdin.fileno(), 'U')

for line in sys.stdin:
    …
```