# Running a R script using hadoop streaming Job Failing : PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 1

Tags: r, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-streaming

I have a R script which works perfectly fine in R Colsole ,but when I am running in Hadoop streaming it is failing with the below error in Map phase .Find the Task attempts log

The Hadoop Streaming Command I have :

```
/home/Bibhu/hadoop-0.20.2/bin/hadoop jar \
   /home/Bibhu/hadoop-0.20.2/contrib/streaming/*.jar \
   -input hdfs://localhost:54310/user/Bibhu/BookTE1.csv \
   -output outsid -mapper `pwd`/code1.sh
```

stderr logs

```
Loading required package: class
Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
  no lines available in input
Calls: read.csv -> read.table
Execution halted
java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 1
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:362)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:572)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.close(PipeMapper.java:136)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:57)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRunner.run(PipeMapRunner.java:36)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:358)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:307)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:170)
```

syslog logs

```
2013-07-03 19:32:36,080 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics.jvm.JvmMetrics: Initializing JVM Metrics with processName=MAP, sessionId=
2013-07-03 19:32:36,654 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask: numReduceTasks: 1
2013-07-03 19:32:36,675 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask: io.sort.mb = 100
2013-07-03 19:32:36,835 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask: data buffer = 79691776/99614720
2013-07-03 19:32:36,835 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask: record buffer = 262144/327680
2013-07-03 19:32:36,899 INFO org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed: PipeMapRed exec [/home/Bibhu/Downloads/SentimentAnalysis/Sid/smallFile/code1.sh]
2013-07-03 19:32:37,256 INFO org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed: Records R/W=0/1
2013-07-03 19:32:38,509 INFO org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed: MRErrorThread done
2013-07-03 19:32:38,509 INFO org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed: PipeMapRed failed!
2013-07-03 19:32:38,557 WARN org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: Error running child
java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 1
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:362)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:572)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.close(PipeMapper.java:136)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:57)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRunner.run(PipeMapRunner.java:36)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:358)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:307)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:170)
2013-07-03 19:32:38,631 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskRunner: Runnning cleanup for the task
```

Comment: Your script **code1.sh** exit abnormally. I think there may be some unexpected input crashing your R script.

Answer (score 0):

1. write hadoopStreamming jar with full version like `hadoop-streaming-1.0.4.jar`
2. specify separate file path for mapper & reducer with -file option
3. tell hadoop which is your mapper & reducer code with -mapper & -reducer option

for more ref see [Running WordCount on Hadoop using R script](https://coderwall.com/p/imxf6g?i=1&p=1&q=author%3asagarnikam123&t%5B%5D=sagarnikam123)

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the logs from your mappers and reducers, since this is the place where the job is failing (as indicated by `java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 1`). This says that your R script crashed.

If you are using the Hortonworks Hadoop distribuion, the easiest way is to open your jobhistory. It should be at `http://127.0.0.1:19888/jobhistory` . It should be possible to find the log in the filesystem using the command line as well, but I haven't yet found where.

1. Open `http://127.0.0.1:19888/jobhistory` in your web browser
2. Click on the *Job ID* of the failed job
3. Click the *number* indicating the failed job count
4. Click an *attempt* link
5. Click the *logs* link

You should see a page which looks something like

```
Log Type: stderr
Log Length: 418
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/root/appcache/application_1404203309115_0003/container_1404203309115_0003_01_000002/./mapper.py", line 45, in <module>
    mapper()
  File "/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/root/appcache/application_1404203309115_0003/container_1404203309115_0003_01_000002/./mapper.py", line 37, in mapper
    for record in reader:
_csv.Error: newline inside string
```

This is an error from my Python script, the errors from R look a bit different.

source: http://hortonworks.com/community/forums/topic/map-reduce-job-log-files/

Answer (score -2):

I received this same error tonight, while also developing Map Reduce Streaming jobs with `R`.

I was working on a 10 node cluster, each with 12 cores, and tried to supply at submission time:

```
-D mapred.map.tasks=200\
-D mapred.reduce.tasks=200
```

The job completed successfully though when I changed these to

```
-D mapred.map.tasks=10\
-D mapred.reduce.tasks=10
```

This was a mysterious fix, and perhaps more context will arise this evening. But if any readers can elucidate, please do!